# How do I access Terminal's selected text using AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I've read through Terminal.app's dictionary and haven't seen a way to access just the selected text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a less hacky way to do this besides using GUI scripting and the clipboard.

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        tell menu bar 1
            click menu item "Copy" of menu "Edit"
            set _selection to the clipboard
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks Graham.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to use a "set myVariable to do shell script..." structure and then parse the answer out of myVariable which will be whatever stdout returned from the shell.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it answers my question. If I have used the mouse to select the word "foobar" somewhere in a Terminal window, I want to be able to run some code to set my AppleScript variable to "foobar". I'm not looking to get the results of some sub-process.

Answer (score 0):

Brian you would run the script provided within a Service script. You would highlight the word, right click and select the service which in turn would tell terminal to copy the word and then make the word a variable which in this example script is being called _selection

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.